# Get data from database inserted in latest 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am in problem in mysql database data retrieving. I have to get latest data inserted within a week or latest 7 days. I just know get data of specific date, but no within a span of days.

Please anyone help me. I am new in mysql.

Comment: `select * from yourtable where date_of_insertion >= (now() - interval 7 day)`

Comment: are you storing the date or time when record was added to db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for INTERVAL. For example, this will find all users whose created_time is in last 7 days and you have field `created_time` to tracked date of creation of record

```
SELECT * from users where created_time > (NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: how about today's day?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = date("your_date_format", strtotime(- 7 days));
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > '$date'");
?>
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below query.

```
SELECT * 
   FROM `table` 
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
 CURDATE()
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),dateField) < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use DATE_SUB Mysql default function

select * from yourtable where date_of_insertion >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select * from tablename where add_time >=  now() - interval 7 day
```